# How to Locate a DYNAMIC Salesforce Lightning INPUT Element with XPATH using C# in Selenium WebDriver

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer, xpath, salesforce-lightning

I need to find out how to Locate a Dynamic Salesforce Lightning Input Element with XPATH using C# in Selenium WebDriver. I just can't get it to work. Below is the code I've tried followed by the HTML and Full XPATH. I get a Bad Token Error and don't know what that means.`Can someone show me a better way like Parent:Child locate? These Lightning Elements are a tough nut to crack...Thanks in Advance!

**C# Selenium WebDriver Code:**

```
//CODE FAILS! //Enter File Number/SSN/TIN ID and Click Search 
**driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[starts-with(@id.'input-')]")).Click();
```

**HTML:**

```
<input name="Participant Id" class="slds-input" id="input-32" aria-describedby="help-message-32" required="" type="text" maxlength="9" pattern="([0-9]*)$" lightning-input_input="">

  <div class="slds-form-element__control slds-grow" lightning-input_input=""><input name="Participant Id" 
  class="slds-input" id="input-32" required="" type="text" maxlength="9" pattern="([0-9]*)$" lightning- 
  input_input=""></div>
  <input name="Participant Id" class="slds-input" id="input-32" required="" type="text" maxlength="9" 
  pattern="([0-9]*)$" lightning-input_input="">
```

**FULL XPATH:**
[`/html/body/div[4]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/c-e-m-p-w-r_-participant-search/article/div[2]/lightning-input/div/input`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGJ9t.png)

**ERROR**:

> {"Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //input[starts-with(@id.'input-')] because of the following error:\nError: Bad token: 'input-'"}

Comment: I can see that you had tried to mention the HTML in the original post but we are not able to see the HTML code. I suggest trying to post the HTML code using the code snippet. It can help to embed the HTML code properly in the post and we can try to check and try to understand the issue in a better way. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting a "." before the double slashes, prior to "input" tag name, and use "@" before Attributes:

driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//input[starts-with(@id.'input-')]")).Click()